# R How to plot a city in Plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I am using Plotly in R and I desire to only show the city of madrid. However, I cannot find a way how to do it.

The closest I have gotten is putting the scope in Europe. If I put in the scope madrid or spain, Still it keeps showing the whole world map. If I put europe, it only shows Europe.

Here is my code:

```
g <- list(
  scope = 'europe',
  landcolor = toRGB("gray95"),
  subunitcolor = toRGB("gray85"),
  countrycolor = toRGB("gray85"),
  countrywidth = 0.5,
  subunitwidth = 0.5
)

plot_geo(data, 
         lat = ~LATITUD, 
         lon = ~LONGITUD) %>%
  add_markers(
    text = ~paste(DISTRITO, TIPO, sep = "<br />")

  ) %>%
  layout(
    title = 'Madrid <br />(Hover for location)', geo = g
  )
```

Comment: Are you bounded to `plotly`? `leaflet` package would be much better for this

Comment: @GGamba No, I am not bounded. Will check it.